# cakephp PaginationRecall component crashes my application with a different url/pages

Tags: cakephp

The PaginationRecall component is giving me a headache, it let my application crash.

I have a region view, I can call it with /views/[number of region]

I found out that the reason for the crash is that it wants to go back to Page:5 
although the url is changed to a different region which only has 1 or 2 pages. 
I updated to the latest cakePHP version [v2.3.5] as there was a mention about a fix for 'Preventing pagiation limit from overflowing the max integer value' But updating didn't solve my problem. Not sure if this is a problem with the PaginationRecal component or the Paginator itself.

For example; I can browse to the url ../regions/view/1/page:5 leave that page and when return back all fine [it remembered last page] 
But when changing the url to a different region ../regions/view/56/ it crashes with error:  Error: The requested address '/regions/view/56' was not found on this server.
Stack Trace

CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 1074

- @deprecated Use PaginatorComponent instead
  */
  public function paginate($object = null, $scope = array(), $whitelist = array()) {
  return $this->Components->load('Paginator', $this->paginate)->paginate($object, $scope, $whitelist);
  }

At first I didn't understand this crash untill I found out it was related to the page number. The problem never pops-up when browsing only on the first page. How can I fix this problem?

I have added the PaginatorRecall Component in my /app/Controller/AppController.php

```
 public $components = array('PaginationRecall');
```

This is the component: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Zaphod/2012/03/27/paginationrecall_for_cakephp_2_x

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

After investigating what the PaginatorRecall component is doing, I found out that it filters out only the page:number and stores it in a session.

I have added a rule to find out if the region is changed and if so then reset the page to page:1

Hope this helps someone else using this component as well.

Comment: you could have put a piece of code that you have added, would be helpful for other users.

Comment: Martin, that is something I could have done, but the code is I think not something for everyone, hence my reason not to publish it. If you want I could post the revamped controller here. But if your solution works, then it is fine. As I commented in the post it is only filtering the page:number.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to this problem and the bug that **PaginationRecall** have with the first page. Surely it is not the most optimal solution, but it is functional.

```
class PaginationRecallComponent extends Component {
    var $components = array('Session');
    var $Controller = null;

    function initialize(&$controller) {
        $this->Controller = & $controller;
        $options = array_merge($this->Controller->request->params, $this->Controller->params['url'], $this->Controller->passedArgs
        );
        $vars = array('page', 'sort', 'direction', 'filter');
        $keys = array_keys($options);
        $count = count($keys);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

            if (!in_array($keys[$i], $vars) || !is_string($keys[$i])) {

                unset($options[$keys[$i]]);
            }
        }
        //save the options into the session
        if ($options) {
            if ($this->Session->check("Pagination.{$this->Controller->modelClass}.options")) {
                $options = array_merge($this->Session->read("Pagination.{$this->Controller->modelClass}.options"), $options);
            }
            $this->Session->write("Pagination.{$this->Controller->modelClass}.options", $options);
            $this->Session->write("region",$this->Controller->modelClass.'/'.$this->Controller->view);
        }
        $region=$this->Session->read('region');
        //recall previous options       
        if ($this->Session->check("Pagination.{$this->Controller->modelClass}.options") && $region==$this->Controller->modelClass.'/'.$this->Controller->view ) {
            $options = $this->Session->read("Pagination.{$this->Controller->modelClass}.options");
            if(!isset($this->Controller->params['named' ]['page']) && isset($this->Controller->params['named' ]['direction']) )               
            {
                $options['page']=1;
            }
            $this->Controller->passedArgs = array_merge($this->Controller->passedArgs, $options);
            $this->Controller->request->params['named'] = $options;
        }
    }
}
```